# How do you join on a like to pg_catalog in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do you join on a like to pg_catalog in Redshift.

```
select table_name, b.query
from information_schema.tables a 
left join pg_catalog.stl_querytext b
on b.query like '%' || a.table_name || '%'
```

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Which info are you trying to get?